# singly linked list element

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm making a program that gives the user to add integer elements, get its length, and get its middle element. My problem is that I don't know what to write for getting the middle element.

```
 public int getLength()
{}

 public Node getMid() {}

 public void insert(int val)
{}

 public void display()
{}
   
public class SinglyLinkedList {
    
       public static void main(String[] args)
{             
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();         
    char ch;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("\nSingly Linked List\n");                     
        System.out.println("Enter integer element to insert:");
        list.insert( scan.nextInt() );       
        System.out.println("Length of the Linked List: "+ list.getLength() );      
        list.display();            
        System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue (Type y or n) \n");
        ch = scan.next().charAt(0);                        
    } while (ch == 'Y'|| ch == 'y');               
}
}
```

Thank you sir Turtle for answering this question.
here is the new edited version:

```
public Node getMid() {
if (length == 0) return null;
int mid = length / 2;
Node ptr = start;
while (mid-- > 0) {
    ptr = ptr.getLink();
}
return ptr;
  }
   public int getLength()
   {}

 public Node getMid() {}

 public void insert(int val)
{}

 public void display()
{}
   
public class SinglyLinkedList {
    
       public static void main(String[] args)
{             
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();         
    char ch;
    do
    {
        System.out.println("\nSingly Linked List\n");                     
        System.out.println("Enter integer element to insert:");
        list.insert( scan.nextInt() );       
        System.out.println("Length of the Linked List: "+ list.getLength() ); 
        list.getMid();      
        list.display();            
        System.out.println("\nDo you want to continue (Type y or n) \n");
        ch = scan.next().charAt(0);                        
    } while (ch == 'Y'|| ch == 'y');               
}
}
```

Hope this gives an idea for other people.
Thank you once again sir Turtle for answering this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already maintained the `length` attribute in your class, we can use that to find the middle of the linked list. In case of an even number of elements in the List, `ceil` is returned *i.e* In case of `1->2->3->4` , `3` is returned.

```
public Node getMid() {
    if (length == 0) return null;
    int mid = length / 2;
    Node ptr = start;
    while (mid-- > 0) {
        ptr = ptr.getLink();
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful. I have added your code in my program and when I do this System.out.println("Middle Element of the Linked List: " + list.getMid());. It keeps displaying the Middle Element of the Linked List: Node@2d6e8792 when I add an element. Do you have any suggestions for this? Thank you again

Comment: `list.getMid()` returns an object of type `Node`, so when it is passed to the print method, it prints `toString` representation on that object. To overcome this we can either implement `toString` method in Node class to return the data or print `list.getMid().data`

Comment: Thank you so much. I have no issues with my program.